# Is it possible to rain dinosaurs?

Tags: weapons, weather, dinosaurs

There are many strange natural phenomenons such as raining objects and live animals from the sky, I'm planning to mass produce hybrid dinosaurs and rain them over my enemy, can it be done in the coming decades? I hope to rain Mosasaurus and preferably Argentinosaurus.

Comment: Rain in the same sense as liquid water falls from clouds, or rain in the sense than an abundance of something falls on something else? Also, with or without killing the dinosaurs?

Comment: @Frostfyre rain in the sense that an overwhelming amount of something falls on enemy's structures and units, it will be better if they can survive the ordeal

Comment: The mechanics of scale work against you. "You can drop a mouse down a thousand-yard mine shaft and, on arriving at the bottom, it gets a slight shock and walks away. A rat is killed, a man is broken, a horse splashes." — J.B.S. Haldane  ( And I don't want to think about dinosaurs.)

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast as long as we can rain dinosaurs whatever happens to them don't matters, death is inevitable I guess.

Answer (score 2):

In the real world, when animals "rain" from the sky, it is usually the result of a tornado having sucked them up somewhere else, usually somewhere nearby.  However, the animals in question are always small ones - fish and small amphibians are the most commonly heard of.  These animals weigh a few ounces, or at the most, a pound or two.

Argentinosaurus weighed something on the order of 80 to 100 **tons**.  Such an enormous animal might be tossed around a bit by a real world tornado, but it certainly wouldn't be sucked into the atmosphere and fall from the clouds.  The idea of a herd of Argentinosauruses (Argentinosauri?) being rained down on the earth is even less likely.

If you need it to rain Argentinosauruses, you have to get yourself a MONSTER tornado, with wind speeds in the area of several thousand miles per hour.  Nothing like this exists in the real world, and it would probably be impossible on earth under any circumstances.  A hurricane has enough energy to do this, but is too dispersed;  a tornado is sufficiently limited in range, but lacks the energy.

So I think the best way to make Argentinosaurs rain down from the heavens is to combine the power of a hurricane with the pinpoint focus of a tornado.  Kick the wind speed up to 8,000 miles per hour, and your dinosaurs are flying.